# Xcode 11.4 Circular Reference errors

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

When compiling project on Xcode 11.4 (on previous Xcode project is building fine) I get following 999+ errors (Did clean build and deleted derived data):

```
<unknown>:0: error: circular reference
<unknown>:0: error: circular reference
<unknown>:0: note: through reference here
<unknown>:0: error: circular reference
<unknown>:0: error: circular reference
<unknown>:0: note: through reference here
<unknown>:0: note: through reference here
<unknown>:0: error: circular reference
<unknown>:0: note: through reference here
<unknown>:0: error: circular reference
<unknown>:0: error: circular reference
<unknown>:0: note: through reference here
```

Is this a problem with Xcode 11.4? Is it possible to disable `circular reference` checking option when compiling a project?.

Comment: I'm seeing this as well. For me it's happening when I have both an extension (Swift) and a category (Objective-C) for the same class when the class is in a separate module.

Comment: Can you give more detail. Better logs would be helpful.

Comment: I have the same problem, hoping for a fix.

Comment: I have the same issue with xCode 11.4 GM. Can anybody help? @AlexBartiş ???

Comment: Nope. Still no fix.

Comment: I have the same issue too... and it's on a pod.. so changing the class name inside the pod is out of the question...

Comment: @bclymer can you provide an example of your category and extension?

Comment: @AlexBartiş Would you post a question with more details?

Comment: add this pod 'SideMenu' to your project. you will see the circular error

Comment: Did anyone found a solution to this issue?

Comment: I have 'SideMenu' pod in my project from beginning, I updated Xcode to 11.4 and got this circular error. no solution found yet. Logged the issue on SideMenu GitHub library

Comment: as per the update to my question on GitHub under 'SideMenu' library, suggested to update pod.

Comment: updating 'SideMenu' pod fixed the issue

Answer (score 15):

Just for SideMenu issue, please update pod SideMenu version to 6.4.8 and it solves the problem.

Comment: Exactly my problem.

Comment: The question is not related to SideMenu.

Comment: I can't update the 'SideMenu' version to 6.4.8. 
When I try to pod install with '6.4.8', Error message, could not find compatible version for 6.4.8
up to 6.4.7 is available now.

Comment: @JasonRay try after updating your repo or gems, pod picks version from there then it will update side menu version

Comment: @JasonRay or `pod install --repo-update` also works for me

Answer (score 0):

These days, I encouter this problem with Xcode 14 (coming with iOS 16). My code is working well with Xcode 13 but start breaking since Xcode 14.
I share my case is here so people can refer my case to check similar things in their code
My origin code is

```swift
public protocol Reusable {
  typealias Cell = UITableViewCell & Reusable
  typealias View = UITableViewHeaderFooterView & Reusable

  static var reuseIdentifier: String { get }
}
```

I changed them to

```swift
public typealias ReusableCell = UITableViewCell & Reusable
public typealias ReusableView = UITableViewHeaderFooterView & Reusable

public protocol Reusable {
  static var reuseIdentifier: String { get }
}
```

And it fixes my issue on Xcode 14