# <unknown>:1:1: circular reference XCode 13

Tags: ios, swift, xcode13

When compiling project in `XCode 13.2` getting error, in all previous `XCode` version code working fine. `Xcode 13` and **above** versions throwing **errors** and not getting any specific file or **podname** which is cause to *error*.

- **error**

> /Users/stevesarsawa/Documents/Projects/MyApp/IOS/:1:1: circular reference

- **Images**

[image: Error Image]

[image: Error Image_2]

Here i only getting `<unknown> error`, and not getting any particular **file/class name** or **framework name** which is causing *error*.

Also tried below mentioned question's solution:-

- [xcode 11.4 circular reference errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60213364/xcode-11-4-circular-reference-errors)

> **Note:- *Here i tried to run code from different paths e.g. Desktop/Desktop > Subfolder, Document/Document > Subfolder and many others. But nothing is worked.* And still getting error as attached images.**

Comment: @vardian sir, please can u help me for this?